# SQL Numeric Column forbid Gaps

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm doing invoice table in my database. I need a integer column to store invoice number. This column has to forbid gap between number. Identity doesn't work because on rollback can produce a gap.

So what I want is:

```
InvoiceId(Primary key identity)     InvoiceNumber(Unique, NOT NUll)
      1                                      1
      2                                      2
      10                                     3
      13                                     4
```

Is there a special way in sql to do this ?
If there is no solution in sql, how should I do it in c# + entity?

EDIT 1:
additionnal information: A row will be never deleted.

EDIT 2:
Why I need gapLess Column: it's a law requirement (french law). Invoice number as to be gapLess, to show that you didn't removed invoice.

Comment: So the column doent allow gaps, but your business process allows gaps? What is a gap? Like a NULL value EG... 1,2,NULL,3,4?

Comment: If you are not allowed to have gaps, you practically removed the availability of more than a single connection. Are you prepared to work with a single connection to this database for *all* your applications?

Comment: @RohanBüchner Gap is 1,2,5,6,7. Is not an null issue. the column is not null.

Comment: @nvoigt really ? No I'm not prepared for this :). That's why I ask the question here ;)

Comment: What about getting the max invoice number then incriminating the value for the new entry programatically?

Comment: @RohanBüchner If two different connection request at the same time, they'll get the same invoice number, will raise an error because invoiceNumber will be the same (question edited to add unique contraint on invoiceNumber)

Comment: If there are to be no gaps then we can assume that deletion never occurs? In that case, you can just run a `ROW_NUMBER()` over the identity column and trust that the results will be stable (because deletes never happen) and so don't (necessarily) have to store this value (but you could of course choose to do so)

Comment: Please explain this requirement to have gapless `InvoiceNumber`s.  I've coded plenty of invoicing systems and have never run across this requirement.  What's special about your situation?

Comment: As per Damien_The_Unbeliever It's better to use Row_Number() in your case.

Comment: @SamAxe question edited

Comment: As this is SQL Server, a more robust solution might be a [`SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).

Comment: @SamAxe hummm, and what 's happen when two different user insert at the same time a new invoice. They will get the same row_number() and add a new row with the same invoiceNumber, right ? (I'm ok, it's rare but can happen)

Comment: @Julian50: yeah, that's why a SEQUENCE is better.  You won't get collisions like that, and it has more accurate semantics for the issue you are modeling.

Comment: @SamAxe Ok for SEQUENCE, it seems hard to do for a none sql expert as me. I use c# + entity framework and I was expecting a sql solution that I could translate in my application. By your way I have to create stored procedure with a transaction ( because I insert rows in other table as well in the same transaction) too hard for me I think... Maybe Is there a way with a locker on the DB during my c# transactionscope ?

Comment: You don't need a stored proc.  Just select the next value from the sequence.  You can use it anytime you like.

Comment: @SamAxe (sorry for this long discussion) After more reading about SEQUENCE, I understand that is almost like identity. I mean SEQUENCE will protect me to get the same number. BUT it won't protected me from a gap in this following scenario. User 1 ask for next value in the sequence and get 1, User 2 ask for next value and get 2. User1 don't insert in the invoice table because of error. but user 2 succeed. then I get a gap. number 1 is missing. I hope is not too messy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to protect from gaps if you access your database in parallel.

Simple case:

1. Process A) creates an invoice. (#1)
2. Process B) creates an invoice. (#2)
3. Process A) rolls back it's transaction.
4. Gap.

You could either lock your whole table for the whole transaction. That means that only one of your processes can create an invoice at the same time. That might be acceptable for small companies where one person creates all invoices by hand.

Or you could leave the column empty and once per night you lock the whole table and write those numbers that are not set yet. That means you get the invoice number later in your invoice process, but it's without gaps.

Or you could read the requirements again. Germany had something equally stupid, but it was only meant to have those numbers on the form for the tax department. So you could use your normal invoice numbers with gaps and when sending them to this bureaucratic monstrosity, you would generate a unique, gap free number on export only.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are multiple users you can't recalculate value at client side. Just create triggers in your database for insert/delete that will recalculate the InvoiceNumber for the entire table.